# xsd to java objects with custom types in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, xsd, jaxb

I am using jaxb parser and able to get java objects from the xsd but have an issue where elements have type attributes. Below is the snippet of xsd. In this case jaxb parser is only creating TestExample_Type java object. I also need TestExample java object which is not happening. If its just 1 element I have a workaround by changing the xsd but there are other 1000 different elements with type datatypes.

Please provide resolution if you have come across this issue

```
<xsd:element name="TestExample" type="TestExample_Type" />
<xsd:complexType name="TestExample_Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="AuthRequest" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Please post the generated Java code for this snippet of XSD.

Comment: import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;  
import javax.xml.binding.annotation.XMLAccessType;  
import javax.xml.binding.annotation.XMLAccessorType;  
import javax.xml.binding.annotation.XMLElement;  
import javax.xml.binding.annotation.XMLType;

@XMLAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
@XMLType(name="TestExample_Type",propOrder= {  
  "authRequest"  
})


public class TestExampleType {

 protected String authRequest;

 public String getAuthRequest() {
  return authRequest;
 }

 public void setAuthRequest(String authRequest) {
  this.authRequest = authRequest;
 }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add that Java code - it is impossible to read it in a comment. I suggest that you read the StackOverflow guidelines about asking questions - it takes time to do it properly.